# Get new value selected in ng-option on change in a multiple select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, multiple-select

I have in my .html page a dropdown list as a multiple select:

```
 <select class="form-control"
         multiple
         ng-model="filter.types"
         ng-change="onChange()"
         ng-options="option for option in filterOptions.types">
    {{option}}
 </select>
```

In my controller, I have the onChange function:

```
$scope.onChange= function(newOptionSelected){
    console.log(newOptionSelected);
}
```

Here I want to get the current item being added to the selected filter.types.
How could I achieve this?

If it was a single select I could pass simply the ng-model to the onChange function.

```
<select class="form-control"
     ng-model="filter.type"
     ng-change="onChange(filter.type)"
     ng-options="option for option in filterOptions.types">
{{option}}
```

But how to achieve this with a multiple select?

Any ideas? :)

I want to delete all the elements selected if the option added is "All". And if the "All" option is selected, then when I select the next item I need to remove only the "All" option.

[image]

Comment: What exactly stops you from selecting a model? [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xHoSCc4qEoGr4rAagoJT?p=preview)

Comment: I can, but I want to know which element was currently added to the array of selected options.  Because if the selected option is "All" I want to empty the array and leave only the "All" options. I can search for indexOf('all) and remove all the elements if the index is > than 0. But then if I have selected "all" and I want to select something different it wont work. If I know that the currently added item is "all" I can remove all. And if it is something diferent I can remove the "all" option.

Comment: well this would be a great addition to your question, I suggest you edit it with this info

Comment: By the moment I resolved this using an auxiliary array and checking if the index of "all" was already in the selected options. But not so nice, I hope to find a nicer option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve this using `ng-change` because you need to keep track of what was the last selected option. You have to `$watch` your `filter.types` which is an array and then based on new value and old value you can decide what to do.

```
$scope.$watch('filter.types', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal.length > oldVal.length) { //Updating only on selecting 
        var lastSelectedOption = [];
        lastSelectedOption = $scope.diff(newVal, oldVal);
        if (lastSelectedOption[0] == 'All') { 

          var i = newVal.length;
          while (i--) {
            if (newVal[i] != 'All') {
              newVal.splice(i, 1); //Deleting other options
            }
          }
        } else if (newVal.indexOf('All') > -1) { 
          newVal.splice(newVal.indexOf('All'), 1); //Deleting 'All' option
        }
      }

    });
```

Working [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/taagwdjp/) for your reference. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That was really useful. Using a watcher does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You can check documentation of angular to get answer to this question. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

```
Plunker:- https://plnkr.co/edit/rhX9AiAhPfHXB2c2BUZF?p=preview
```